# Writing SQL into Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

How can i write this SQL query into Relational algebra?

```
Select Distinct S.Name
From Student S, Transcript T1, Transcript T2
WHERE T1.StudId = S.Id AND T2.StudId = S.Id And
(T1.Semester =’S1997’ AND T2.Semester = ’F1998’)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to say exact expression when I can't test it and I don't know your relation schema, but try smth like this

```
\project_{Name}
{
    {
        Student \join_{Id = StudId} \select_{Semester='S1997'} Transcript
    } \join_{Id = StudId}
    {
       \select_{Semester='F1998'} Transcript
    }
}
```